# reading file then converting string to ascii to make a frequency counter java

Tags: java

Hello with this code I am trying to read a file. After I read the file, I am trying to get the ascii value of each character in the file and then make a frequency counter of uppercase characters, lowercase characters, and numbers

With my code, I try to read the file by line and put them in each array accordingly. Then I can use the array as a frequency counter to see how many uppercase character, lowercase character, and numbers there are.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Counting 
{
    char[] upper;
    char[] lower;
    int[] num;
    int u1 = 0;
    int l1= 0;
    int n1 = 0;
    File inFile;

public void ReadFile( String nfile ) throws IOException
{
    inFile  = new File( nfile );
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( inFile ) );
    //... Loop as long as there are input lines.
    String speech = null;
    //char[] charArray = null;

    while ( ( speech = reader.readLine() ) != null) 
    {
        int slength = speech.length();

        //charArray = speech.toCharArray();



        AddToArrays(speech, slength);

    }

    //... Close reader and writer.
    reader.close();  // Close to unlock.
}

public void AddToArrays(String c, int l)
{
    /*for(int i = 0; i < l; i++)
    {
        if( (int) c[u1] > 64 && (int) c[u1] < 91)
        {
            upper[u1] = c[i];
            u1++;
        }
        if( (int) c[l1] > 96 && (int) c[l1] < 123)
        {
            lower[l1] = c[i];
            l1++;
        }
        if( (int) c[n1] > 47 && (int) c[n1] < 58)
        {
            num[l1] = c[i];
            n1++;
        }
    }*/
    for(int i = 0; i < l ; i++)
    {
        char character = c.charAt(i);
        int ascii = (int) character;

        if( ascii > 64 && ascii < 91)
        {
            upper[u1] = character;
            u1++;
        }
        if( ascii > 96 && ascii < 123)
        {
            lower[l1] = character;
            l1++;
        }
        if( ascii > 47 && ascii < 58)
        {
            lower[n1] = character;
            n1++;
        }
    }

}

public void DisplayResults(int u, int l, int n)
{
    System.out.println("Upper characters: " + u);
    System.out.println("lower characters: " + l);
    System.out.println("Numbers:          " + n);
}

public static void main( String[] args ) 
{
    try
    {
        Counting rFile = new Counting();
        rFile.ReadFile( "Speech.txt" );
        rFile.DisplayResults( rFile.u1, rFile.l1, rFile.n1 );

    }
    catch ( IOException e )
    {
        System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
    }

}

}
```

I get the following errors:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

at Counting.AddToArrays(Counting.java:64)

at Counting.ReadFile(Counting.java:29)

at Counting.main(Counting.java:93)

I recently started java programming.

If anyone can help, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just declaring your arrays and no where in your code initialising them:

```
char[] upper;
char[] lower;
```

So when you try to access an element in these arrays, you will get `NullPointerException`:

```
        upper[u1] = character;

        lower[l1] = character;
```

You need to initialise these arrays before using them:

```
upper = new char[desiredLength];
lower = new char[desiredLength];
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the quick reply.
I have tried that. though I'm not sure where exactly to put it. I tried putting it in the AddToArray function, but I get the error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
 at Counting.AddToArrays(Counting.java:70)
 at Counting.ReadFile(Counting.java:30)
 at Counting.main(Counting.java:99)

Comment: @loktd You can initialise them with declaration: char upper = new char[desiredLength];
Also IndexOutOfBoundException means that array size is smaller than the index you are trying to access.

Comment: oh thank you Because I did not know the exact characters of the speech, I didn't know what to use for the desiredLength.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public long ReadFile(String sfile) throws IOException 
    {
        inFile  = new File(sfile);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inFile));
        //... Loop as long as there are input lines.
        String speach = null;
        while ((speach=reader.readLine()) != null) 
        {

            System.out.println(speach);

        }

        while ( ( speach = reader.readLine() ) != null) 
        {
            int slength = speach.length();

            //charArray = speach.toCharArray();



            AddToArrays(speach, slength);

        }
        //... Close reader and writer.
        reader.close();  // Close to unlock.
        return inFile.length();

    }
```

Comment: can you explain it a bit?